# Where is PricebookEntry Object

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, pricebook

i am following this link http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_products.htm .In this ER diagram there is Pricebook2Id  field on Opportunity Object but i can't see any field in Opportunity Object in my dev org which is related to Pricebook.In this there is an object mentioned PricebookEntry object but there is Pricebook Object but no PricebookEntry object.Where are these fields and objects .can u please clarify ??

screen shot of Opportunity Fields [image]

here is no Pricebook2Id field.

Comment: Where are you checking this field and object for ?I would recommend you to check backend in schema explorer rather than front end .

Comment: i saw all the fields of Opportunity.giving screen shot of that in question.there is no field name as Pricebook2Id.but its mentioned in ER diagram.

Comment: sorry on a network where these images are blocked ..hold on i will see my mobile and get back

Comment: Yes saw the screenshot .These objects will be visible in your database .Not from SFDC UI.So you wont find them .Hope that helps .As below ProcebookEntry is junction between Pricebook2 and Product2

Answer (score 3):

To add to Artur's explanation ..

A PricebookEntry (PBE) is a junction record between a Product2 and a Pricebook2. It represents a price for a given currency.

```
Example: Three currencies USD, AUD, GBP

Standard pricebook - PBE USD 10.00 - Product2 SKU AAA
Standard pricebook - PBE AUD 11.00 - Product2 SKU AAA
Standard pricebook - PBE GBP 7.00 - Product2 SKU AAA

Custom pricebook1  - PBE USD 10.00 - Product2 SKU AAA
Custom pricebook1 - PBE AUD 11.00 - Product2 SKU AAA
Custom pricebook1 - PBE GBP 7.00 - Product2 SKU AAA

Custom pricebook2  - PBE USD 5.00 - Product2 SKU AAA
Custom pricebook2 - PBE AUD 5.50 - Product2 SKU AAA
Custom pricebook2 - PBE GBP 3.50 - Product2 SKU AAA
```

where custom pricebook1 is your commercial pricebook
where custom pricebook2 is your non-profit/government pricebook

Answer (score 2):

PriceBookEntry:

`Represents a product entry (an association between a Pricebook2 and Product2) in a price book.`

You create PricebookEntry for example when you create standard price on product.
And thats why you can find `PriceBookEntryId` field on opportunity product

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_pricebookentry.htm

Answer (score 0):

**Price Books** are list of products and their associated prices. Each product and its price is called a price book entry.  So, if you want to speak in relationship terms, a Product may be on multiple Pricebooks; this is managed with a junction record called PricebookEntry.[image]
See [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000CxSwAAK) for more